# iPhone Slide Tap Delete

Tags: iphone, file-io

Does the slide tap delete (i.e., deleting a video in Videos app) come default when you make an iPhone vertical table? If not, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comes as default when you make that table editable.  All you have to do is implement the delegate functions to allow editing mode on the table, and of course place the editing button somewhere.

Comment: It should be in the .m file if you try to make a TableView application.